# Faster way to compute distributions from Markov chain?

Tags: performance, julia, markov-chains

Suppose that I have a probability transition matrix, say a matrix of dimensions 2000x2000, that represents a homogeneous Markov chain, and I want to get some statistics of each probability distribution of the first 200 steps of the chain (the distribution of the first row at each step), then I've written the following

```
using Distributions, LinearAlgebra

# This function defines our transition matrix:
function tm(N::Int, n0::Int)
    [pdf(Hypergeometric(N-l,l,n0),k-l) for l in 0:N, k in 0:N]
end

# This computes the 5-percentile of a probability vector
function percentile5(M::Vector)
    s=0
    i=0
    while s <= 0.05
        i += 1
        s += M[i]
    end
    return i-1
end

# This function compute a matrix with three rows: means, 5-percentiles 
# and standard deviations. Each column represent a session.
function stats(N::Int, n0::Int, m::Int)    
    A = tm(N,n0)
    B = I # Initilizing B with the identity matrix
    sup = 0:N # The support of each distribution
    sup2 = [k^2 for k in sup]
    stats = zeros(3,m)
    for i in 1:m
        C = B[1,:]
        stats[1,i] = sum(C .* sup) # Mean
        stats[2,i] = percentile5(C) # 5-percentile
        stats[3,i] = sqrt(sum(C .* sup2) - stats[1,i]^2) # Standard deviation
        B = A*B
    end
    return stats
end

data = stats(2000,50,200)
```

My question is, there is a more efficient (faster) way to do the same computation? I don't see a better way to do it but maybe there are some tricks that speed-up this computation.

Comment: You might want to go with an ensemble method because the large matrix multiplies are hard. i.e. run the chain many times from random initialization for `m` steps. Do the stats as if ensemble are the distribution.

Comment: @Dan can you give me some reference to this? I don't know what an ensemble is (I'm not programmer, just do some casual programming)

Comment: Try replacing `B = A*B` with `C = A*C`, and put the `C = B[1,:]` above the loop. Additionally,  add `using SparseArrays` and replace `A = tm(N, n0)` with `A = sparse(tm(N,n0))`. If things don't work out, I'll take a closer look and write a full answer. As for ensemble methods - ensembles are simply collections of simulations (haven't found the best reference, but many Stats/DataScience texts discuss this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have running so far:

```
using Distributions, LinearAlgebra, SparseArrays

# This function defines our transition matrix:
function tm(N::Int, n0::Int)
    [pdf(Hypergeometric(N-l,l,n0),k-l) for l in 0:N, k in 0:N]
end

# This computes the 5-percentile of a probability vector
function percentile5(M::AbstractVector)
    s = zero(eltype(M))
    res = length(M)
    @inbounds for i = 1:length(M)
        s += M[i]
        if s > 0.05
            res = i - 1
            break
        end
    end
    return res
end

# This function compute a matrix with three rows: means, 5-percentiles 
# and standard deviations. Each column represent a session.
function stats(N::Int, n0::Int, m::Int)
    A = sparse(transpose(tm(N, n0)))
    C = zeros(size(A, 1))
    C[1] = 1.0
    sup = 0:N # The support of each distribution
    sup2 = sup .^ 2
    stats = zeros(3, m)
    for i = 1:m
        stats[1, i] = sum(C .* sup) # Mean
        stats[2, i] = percentile5(C) # 5-percentile
        stats[3, i] = sqrt(sum(C .* sup2) - stats[1, i]^2) # Standard deviation
        C = A * C
    end
    return stats
end
```

It is around 4x faster (on smaller parameters - possibly much more speedup on large parameters). Basically uses the tips I've made in the comment:

- using sparse arrays.
- avoiding whole matrix multiply but using vector-matrix multiply instead.

Further improvement are possible (like simulation/ensemble method I've mentioned).

Comment: this is INSANELY faster than before. It took now ~1.2 seconds and before it was around one minute!